# Selenium IDE: Is it possible to continue a failed test after manually fixing an issue?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I'm using the recorder for creating a large test case. The recorder sometimes records a click rather than a clickAndWait which results in a failed test.

When the test fails while running the replay I would like to be able to fix the test and then hit resume. However, I haven't found any way of resuming. I can fix the issue, but then I have to re-run the test from the beginning...

Does anyone know of any selenium version that has this kind of resuming functionality? I'm currently using Selenium IDE 1.10.0.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know about any Selenium part (or even 3rd party library) that would allow such a behaviour. That said, I might be wrong. I'm almost certain, though, that if it existed, it wouldn't be for Selenium IDE - that's supposed to be easy and small extension. Hopefully someone will write this someday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont know there is a resume option but we can start the play back from the error position by using "set/clear start point" ,right click on the position you want to resume and select set/ clear  start point

[image]

Comment: Yup. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!!